# Log private iPhone methods

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, logging

Is there any way to log private methods etc through Xcode?  Example would be:

User presses a button.  Console logs information of everything that took place when the user pressed the button.  Im thinking along the lines of how you can log SQL output to the debugger and see everything thats going on.

Reason is that I am trying to work with some of the private frameworks, specifically the one(s) that control sending email.  It would be helpful if there was some way to see what is called between when the MFMailComposeViewController is called , the user presses send, and when its dismissed.  Sorting through the private headers would be a little easier if there was some way to know exactly what was being used.

....hope that clarifies my question.

Edit:

Even something as simple as this:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

But that could be applied to private frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of would be one of the following:

```
NSLog( @"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols] )
NSLog( @"%@", [NSThread callStackReturnAddresses] )
```

**However**, you may not end up finding what you want since you are getting into jailbreak territory. Keep that in mind depending on where you intend to publish your application.

You **might** find more information about the private APIs [here](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks), but I can't guarantee how useful or up to date they are. Also lots of searches about the private APIs lead to a program called [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/).

**UPDATE**:

Out of curiosity, does the `MFMailComposerDelegate`method `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` not provid enough informaion? When called, you get the result (failed,cancelled,saved,sent) and an error object (with potentially more details) in the event sending mail failed ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate)).

Comment: Thanks! The purpose would be to see what method is called by the "sent" button in order to automate that by using the private headers of that class and then calling that method myself.  The delegate method just provides the after effect of what occurred.

Comment: This is also for an enterprise app so the app store restrictions don't apply for this particular app.  Aside from finding how to do this one particular thing a second reason was so that checking updated versions of iOS for changes in the private frameworks wouldnt require dumping the headers and searching through them every time.

Comment: @DanaK Understandable, but even with the enterprise account, Apple does not make it any easier. Restrictions aside, the private APIs are still buried deep.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_msgSend` function, this will trap every objective-c method call.